# How to send control C to Mac Terminal using python?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, interrupt

I have a python script that needs to send control C to the mac terminal. I've tried sending the plain text "^C" but I get back that the terminal does not recognize the command. (The terminal meaning the pseudo terminal that python creates)

Basically, I am using the terminal to run an old Unix Executable and the only way that I can think of to terminate this gracefully is to send the interrupt signal. Is there any way I can fool the terminal into thinking that I pressed control C?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly send the SIGINT signal to the process if you can get its PID using [`os.kill`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill).

```
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

This will require you to instrument your script to grab the process PID, but it's the best way to emulate the "ctrl-c" behavior.

Comment: If the tool isn't interactive, wouldn't `SIGTERM` be just as / more appropriate? I always figured it's the shell that interprets `SIGINT` if it's not caught by the underlying command and terminates the command for you.

Comment: ... And for those unfamiliar with signals, when you type control-c in a terminal, it typically sends a signal rather than sending a literal control-c to the application. The application never sees the control-c character, which is why just printing or piping a control-c to the application never works.

Comment: Ah...that's why...that makes more sense now.

Comment: Any hints on getting the PID?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the process using `subprocess`'s `Popen`, you should be able to send a control signal like this:

```
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

You'll need to `import signal` to get `SIGINT`.