# Send ctrl-C to OSX Terminal in an SSH Session in Python

Tags: python, macos, ssh

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570297/130427) requires me to run Python on the same machine as the process I am trying to terminate.

However, I'm running Python locally and have the process running over SSH in Terminal. How do I send the terminate command in this situation?

Comment: If you just want send ctrl-C, ssh and kill with the process id

Comment: Ah. SSH within the Python script? A little more involved than I was hoping, since it requires authentication. I can send Terminal commands using Applescript. I wonder if there is an Applescript Terminal command for ctrl-C.

Comment: SSH in python you can check module pexpect

Comment: I am trying to figure what possible reason you would want to do this. Can you explain why you are trying to control a remote process over ssh using python? Is there any reason you can't run the python script on the remote server?

Comment: I'm editing programs remotely using Cyberduck for SFTP and Sublime Text 2 for editing. I have a hotkey on Alfred to send `make` then `make run` to Terminal (cmd+M) so that I don't have to cmd+tab to Terminal. I'm refactoring code and just checking that new code didn't break anything. The `make run` starts the program running a long string of output and as long as it is doing that, I know it is not broken. I would like to be able to terminate the program using another simple Alfred hotkey (e.g. cmd+shift+C) so I don't have to switch focus to Terminal to stop it and can keep programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH using `pexpect` after setting up `ssh-keygen` with the server so that it doesn't require a password from your machine:

```
import pexpect

ssh_command = 'ssh user@your.server.com'
child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_command)

default_prompt = 'user@server:~/# '
child.expect(default_prompt)

kill_command = 'killall process_name'
child.sendline(kill_command)
```

If you don't use `ssh-keygen`, [you will need to work your password login into the `pexpect` script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234272/130427) before the `default_prompt` line.

Just attach this script to a hotkey (e.g. `ctrl+alt+c`) using Alfred.